# Saving gravity PDF to local computer

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to get the PDF generated from gravity PDF saved locally or access the URL of the PDF created in a variable. Is this possible? I found https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v4/development-helper-parameters/ and it seems promising but not sure how to access the URL generated.

Comment: Is the purpose, for your users to be able to get it back from a "my account" style page? Since the link is already sent via email when first submitted.

Comment: if the user submits a form on their "my account " style page then it saves the  pdf that to their sharePoint folder.I want to be able to access that url  to use the functionality built in a difference application.Is there another way besides  via email,although that is a viable option?

Comment: I made a piece of code last year that execute the gravitypdf shortcode and pulls a formated link to a viewable pdf generated from an entry by user. I don't if it still works but if it sounds close to a viable option i can paste it as an answer and you could tinker with it.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of code in question (not the sexiest code but worked at the time)

Basically drop the shortcode `[custom_pdf_entries]` on a specific page that your user access, this will look for all the entries and look for a gravitypdf ID to pull the formated PDF generated with the entry in question.

```
add_shortcode("custom_pdf_entries", array($this,'custom_get_form_entry'));

/*
* Get All PDF from Form exclude those we dont want
*/
function custom_get_form_entry($atts){            
    $search_arg = array(
        'status' => 'active',
        'field_filters' => array(
            'mode' => 'all',
            array(
                'key'   => 'created_by',
                'value' =>  get_current_user_id()
            )
        )
    );

    $sorting = array(
            'key' => '1',
            'direction' => 'ASC'
    );

    $all_forms = GFAPI::get_forms();
    $excluded_id = explode("," , $atts['exclude']);

    ob_start();

    foreach($all_forms as $key => $a_val){

        if( !in_array($a_val['fields'][0]->formId, $excluded_id) ){
            $entries = GFAPI::get_entries($a_val['fields'][0]->formId,$search_arg,$sorting);
            $count = 1;

            if(count($a_val['gfpdf_form_settings']) > 0){
                $gravity_pdf_form_id = current(array_keys($a_val['gfpdf_form_settings']));

                if($entries){
                    foreach($entries as $key => $val){
                        echo do_shortcode('[gravitypdf name="Forms" type="download" id="'.$gravity_pdf_form_id.'" text="'.$a_val['title'].' #'.$count.'" entry="'.$val['id'].'"]');
                        echo '<br/><br/>';
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Note: some modification maybe required also i can probably help you if anything arise